# how do I find the value of a parameter when others are given and integral is zero using matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, int

I have a function

```
function y = testf(x,F,phi,M,beta,alpha)
y = -((F+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x))).*M.^3.*(cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+M.*beta.*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)))./((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+(-1+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.^2.*beta).*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M))- (alpha.*(M.^2.*(F+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x))).*(-1+2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).^2.*M.^2+ cosh(2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)-2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*sinh(2.*(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)))./(8.*((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.*cosh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)+(-1+(1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M.^2.*beta).*sinh((1 + phi.*cos(2.*pi.*x)).*M)).^2));
```

integrating with

```
q = quad(@(x) testf (x, F, phi,M, beta, alpha), 0, h);
```

when q = 0 and x,F,phi,M,beta, how do I find alpha and draw the streamline?

Comment: can you please give some numbers to experiment with :)

Comment: beta = 0.03, alpha = 0.2, M = 2, phi = 0.6, x = 0.5, when F = theta-1, what is theta if integral is zero. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you gave some numbers, but here is how you would start this. It assumes you are using a version of Matlab that has MuPad as the Symbolic Engine.

First of all, I wouldn't use `quad` because symbolic expressions will be involved, use `int` instead.

If I understood you correctly, have the values of `x, F, phi, M, beta` and you would like to solve for `alpha` when `q = 0`

```or-none
%define the known variables first

syms alpha %defining symbolic object
```

Now, the following may not work because it's a huge function:

```
q = int(y,x,0,h)
```

If it did, all you have to do is solve and evaluate the results for alpha (this may not work as well):

```
alpha = eval( solve( 'q' , alpha ) )
```

If the above didn't achieve anything, you might what to look at the `'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints'` option.